# the rate of data transmission between two nodes with SNMP

Tags: networking, monitoring, snmp

I want to estimate the rate of data transmission between two nodes. After surfing the internet I found a solution. The solution states that in order to get the transmission rate first of all I should request an ifInOctets then after a while (for example 1 second) I should request again and hence by subtracting the two results I get the answer which is the rate of transmission. The problem is that after requesting  ifInOctets I get a list of 14 values. How can i use these values to get my unit rate. The following is image of the values.
[image]

Comment: Each interface keeps its own statistics. You need to use the interface that's used to connect to the other node.

Comment: The solution you found seems to assume that the only network communication the device is doing is with the other node.

Comment: ifTable is a table, so anything you grab under it should be interpreted as a column value of a row. http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/mibs/interfaces.html If possible, grab the whole table and learn it.